# why does if not operation == '/' or '*' or '+' or '-': give me a syntax error,

Tags: python

```py
if not operation == '/' or '*' or '+' or '-':
  print('not a valid answer, try again')
  operation = (input('Please enter what operation you would like to do, / is divide, * is multiply, + is plus and - is minus')
```

Comment: Can you put your code into a block to make it easier to see what is happening?

Comment: @jarmod thats not the cause of the SytaxError

Comment: @frederic yes, you're right, thanks. *A* problem for sure, but not *the* problem. The OP's question title was a red herring.

Comment: Caused by a typo, as per [@frederic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65878079/1431750) _(which should have just been a comment)_. But the reason it won't work after that fix, is coz the code doesn't do what OP thinks it does. For that see [Timur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65878040/1431750).

Comment: @jarmod who spotted the ___real___ cause ?

Comment: Now who closed this question ?

Comment: The syntax error is coming from the unclosed parentheses.  However, `not operation == '/' or '*' or '+' or '-'` is not doing what you think it is doing (when you correct the syntax error)

Comment: @iidynamix Please accept the answer that helped you most using they grey checkmark on the left of it !

Answer (score 3):

> `operation = (input('Please enter what operation you would like to do, / is divide, * is multiply, + is plus and - is minus')`

You forgot to add a second  closing brace. In this case, just remove the opening brace.

Additionally, your `if` statement will always be True. Following code will work:

```py
if not operation in ['/', '*', '+', '-']: # test if operation is one of /, *, + and -
  print('not a valid answer, try again')
  operation = input('Please enter what operation you would like to do, / is divide, * is multiply, + is plus and - is minus')
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean something like this? Note the corrected syntax and logic. Use an infinite loop, prompt for the user input **before** you check that input. Exit from the loop (`break`) when `operation` belongs to the set of allowed values. Otherwise, repeat the loop and prompt for the user input again. Use [f-strings or formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) to print incorrect input (make the user error easier to see).

```
while True:
    operation = input('Please enter what operation you would like to do, / is divide, * is multiply, + is plus and - is minus: ')
    if operation in {'/', '*', '+', '-'}:
        break
    print(f'Not a valid answer: {operation}, try again')
```

Answer (score 0):

Each clause that is broken up by an `or` statement is its own Boolean.

So `if not operation == '/' or '*' or '+' or '-':` really represents four different Booleans:

1. `if not operation == '/'`
2. `'*'`
3. `'+'`
4. `'-'`

To correct this, you need to write each statement as its own conditional:

1. `if not operation == '/'`
2. `if not operation == '*'`
3. `if not operation == '+'`
4. `if not operation == '-'`

Or, strung together,

```
if not operation == '/' or not operation == '*' or not operation == '+' or not operation == '-'
```

Comment: The first part of what you were trying to explain is correct but the "strung together" version is wrong. (Check with an invalid `operation` like `x` or a valid one like `*` and you get `True` in both cases.) When you put them together like that, it should be joined with `and`'s, not `or`'s. Like this: `if not operation == '/' and not operation == '*' and not operation == '+' and not operation == '-': print('error')`. Also, you're missing a `==` before `'-'` at the end.